# Why does my footstep sound repeat infinitely even though i'm using a coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update()
{
isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
 x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
 z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
StartCoroutine(FootStepSounds());
}



    IEnumerator FootStepSounds()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (x > 0 || z > 0)
            {
                //tried to reverse the order, still nothing
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
                FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("Foot");
                
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Here is a piece of code that's taken from my script.
I had hoped that since I'm using a coroutine, it would wait for the interval of WaitForSeconds and then play again, but it just repeats infinitely as if there was no timer or anything.

Can you please help me figure out why this won't run?
A tip about how to write footstep scripts would also be very appreciated!

P.S: When I say it is a piece, I mean that literally: this is not the entire code and the Update function is merely just so you know I haven't messed up the variables I'm referencing.

Comment: Because you call it every frame?

Comment: I thought about it, but I thought the coroutine WaitForSeconds would solve that since I am telling it to wait.
Can you recommend me a way around this?

Comment: to just repeat this call infinitely at an interval you could just make a while loop in the coroutine like while(enabled) { waitForSecond() do footstep calculation; } and call that once OnEnable not on Update

Comment: You are starting a new Coroutine every frame ...

Answer (score 0):

There's another approach, which would be to ditch the coroutine altogether and just use the Update function:

```
public AudioManager audioManager;
private float timer = 0f;

void Update ( )
{
    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere ( groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask );
    x = Input.GetAxis ( "Horizontal" );
    z = Input.GetAxis ( "Vertical" );
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if ( isGrounded && timer > 1f )
    {
        if ( x > 0 || z > 0 )
        {
            timer = 0;
            audioSource.Play ( "Foot" );
        }
    }
}
```

You can get fancier if you want, and expose a float variable for the minimum time between footfalls. But, this should get you started.